# Haskell recursive function which splits a string of words into individual string

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn haskell I am stuck on the following question

Write down a function split :: RawText -> [Word] that splits a given string
into a lists of words.

To keep things simple, we assume that the raw text is a string of letters and blanks only, possibly with an irregular spacing.
For example: split " one two three ff " = ["one","two","three","ff"]

I keep getting ["one"*** Exception: recursion.hs:30:1-14: Non-exhaustive patterns in function spilt' so the recursion is never ending however I have a base case.

My function

```
type RawText = String
-- [Char] 'a','b','c','d','e'
type SingleWord = String
type Line = [SingleWord]
type Page = [Line]

--        [-------CHAR-----]
-- split " one two three ff " = ["one","two","three","ff"]
--                              [char],[char],[char],[char]
-- " " is delimiter for a []

split' :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
spilt' [] = []
split' xs
    | xs == [] = []
    | isBlank (head xs) = split' xs
    | otherwise = waitForBlank xs : spilt' (tail xs)

isBlank :: Char -> Bool
isBlank x = if x == ' ' then True else False

waitForBlank :: String -> String
waitForBlank [] = []
waitForBlank (x:xs)
    | isBlank x = []
    | otherwise = x : waitForBlank xs
```

Comment: Enabling warnings would have helped here in spotting the typo `spilt`, generating a message like "missing signature for `spilt`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (feedback welcome,newbie here)

```
split' :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
split' [] = []
split' (x:xs)
    | isBlank x = split' xs
    | otherwise = waitForBlank (x:xs) : split' (drop (length (waitForBlank (x:xs))) xs)

isBlank :: Char -> Bool
isBlank x = if x == ' ' then True else False

waitForBlank :: String -> String
waitForBlank [] = []
waitForBlank (x:xs)
    | isBlank x = []
    | otherwise = x : waitForBlank xs
```

Comment: Congratulations, you got it! This solution may work, but it can be improved by using library function which eliminate explicit recursion (which is considered unpleasant by many functional programmers). See my answer for an example how to use predefined functions.

Answer (score 6):

You declare a function `split'` and a function `spilt'`. Correct the typos and you should be good to go!

```
split' :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
spilt' [] = [] -- the first typo is here
split' xs
    | xs == [] = []
    | isBlank (head xs) = split' xs
    | otherwise = waitForBlank xs : spilt' (tail xs) -- here is the second typo
```

To explain the message, it is best to split your code into the two different functions you declared:

```
split' :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
split' xs
    | xs == [] = []
    | isBlank (head xs) = split' xs
    | otherwise = waitForBlank xs : spilt' (tail xs)

-- spilt' :: [a] -> [a] (or something like this)
spilt' [] = []
```

Now when you recurse in `split'`, you call `spilt'`. Since the function `spilt'` you declared doesn't handle the non-empty list, it throws an exception.

---

On a further note, if you correct the typo, you won't have to handle the empty list twice:

```
import Prelude hiding (split)

split :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
split [] = []
split xs
    -- | xs == [] = [] this case is matched by the pattern
    --                 above and thus not needed
    | isBlank (head xs) = split' xs
    | otherwise = waitForBlank xs : split (tail xs)
```

Also, when pattern matching on lists, you can explicitly pattern match against the `head` and `tail` of the list by explicitly writing out the fist `cons` application:

```
split s@(x:xs)
    | isBlank x = split' xs
    | otherwise = waitForBlank s : split' xs
```

But somehow this function still seems kind of clunky, there must be a better way to skip all letters. Let's have a look at the library functions to see what could help us. You can find them [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile):

```
-- drops letters from RawText while a certain predicate holds
dropWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
-- takes letters form RawText while a certain predicate holds
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

These look rather promising. Now we can rewrite `waitForBlank` as:

```
waitForBlank xs = takeWhile (not . isBlank) xs
-- or, pointfree:
waitForBlank = takeWhile (not . isBlank)
```

Using `dropWhile` we can also make the `split` function more efficient by skipping all non-space characters. Note that the space is included in the part of `dropWhile` and has to be dropped explicitly.

```
split :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
split [] = []
split xs = waitForBlank xs : split (dropUntilBlank xs)

-- With dropUntilBlank defined as
dropUntilBlank xs = tail (dropWhile (not . isBlank) xs)

-- without the call of tail, dropUntilBlank would keep the space in between the words:
dropWhile (not . isBlank) "a word" => " word"
--              note the extra space: ^^^

-- using tail on this now produces the correct word:
tail (dropWhile (not . isBlank) "a word") = "word"
```

Now the result looks nice and clean:

```
split :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
split [] = []
split xs = waitForBlank xs : split (dropUntilBlank xs)

waitForBlank xs = takeWhile (not . isBlank) xs

dropUntilBlank xs = tail (dropWhile (not . isBlank) xs)
```

The last part can also be combined by using [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break):

```
split :: RawText -> [SingleWord]
split [] = []
split xs = word : split' rest
     where
         (word, (space:rest)) = break isBlank xs
```

This answer assumes that all words are separated by a single space. For multiple spaces, `dropUntilBlank` has to be rewritten to exclude multiple blanks by substituting `tail` for `dropWhile isBlank`.